# How to put if statement inside button's OnClickListener in Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on my major project and I want my button to open different intents based on the string array value obtained. I used if and else if statements inside the OnClickListener of the button but it won't click anymore. Please help me.

This is my XML file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_large">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_middle"
        android:text="Syllabus"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonpdf"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Open Book" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Java file for the same activity:

```
public class ActivityBookDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_OBJCT = "com.app.sample.recipe.OBJ";

    private Book book;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private View parent_view;

    Button button;
    String[] obj;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_book_details);
        parent_view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonpdf);


        book = (Book) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_OBJCT);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fabToggle();
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(book.getName());

        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(book.getPhoto());

        LinearLayout subjects = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.subjects);


        final String[] title_subjects = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Subjects);
        addIngredientsList(subjects, title_subjects);
        obj = title_subjects;

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ("Soft Computing".equals(obj)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityBookDetails.this, pdfviewactivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if ("Web Engineering".equals(obj)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityBookDetails.this, pdfweben.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if ("Network Management".equals(obj)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityBookDetails.this, pdfnetwork.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if ("Wireless Network".equals(obj)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityBookDetails.this, pdfwireless.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

I want my if else condition to work on the basis of the value of string array.

This is a sample Java file of one of the given intents:

```
public class pdfwireless extends AppCompatActivity {
    PDFView pdfView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdfwireless);
        pdfView = (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("wirelessnetwork.pdf").load();
    }
}
```

Comment: debug it and check the value of `obj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't try to add conditionals inside the `OnClickListener`, instead the simplest thing to do would be to move your conditional logic to another method for example.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    goToNextView();
}

private void goToNextView(){
    if (title_subjects[0] == "Soft Computing") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityBookDetails.this, pdfviewactivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    // else if {}
    // else {}
}
```

As cricket_007 already suggested there are nicer ways than using if/else if statements. If you plan to add a lot more options maybe consider using an enum or map.

```
public enum Subjects {
    SOFT_COMPUTING("Soft Computing", pdfviewactivity.class),
    WEB_ENGINEERING("Web Engineering", pdfweben.class),
    NETWORK_MANAGEMENT("Wireless Network", pdfnetwork.class),
    WIRELESS_NETWORK("Network Management", pdfwireless.class);

    private String name;
    private Class clazz;

    Subjects(String name, Class clazz){
        this.name = name;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public static Class getClass(String title_subject) {
        for(Subjects subject: Subjects.values()) {
            if (subject.name.equals(title_subject)) {
                return subject.clazz;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private void goToNextView() {

    //Alternative to conditionals using Enum
    Class theClassToGoTo = Subjects.getClass(title_subjects[0]);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityBookDetails.this, theClassToGoTo);
    startActivity(intent);

   //Alternative to conditionals using HashMap
    Map<String, Class> subject_map = new HashMap<>();
    subject_map.put("Soft Computing", pdfviewactivity.class);
    subject_map.put("Web Engineering", pdfweben.class);
    subject_map.put("Wireless Network", pdfnetwork.class);
    subject_map.put("Network Management", pdfwireless.class);

    Class theClassToGoTo2 = subject_map.get(title_subjects[0]);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(ActivityBookDetails.this, theClassToGoTo2);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The easiest change would be to use the HashMap, although the downside to this is the `goToNextView` method needs to change every time new subjects are added. The Enum involves a lot more code but is a little easier cleaner since everything just has one purpose to change.

There are other ways you can do this, the above are just two simple suggestions that don't involve changing too much of your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...

```
final String[] title_subjects = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Subjects);
obj = title_subjects;
```

And...

```
if ("Soft Computing".equals(obj)) {
```

(Note: `obj` variable is pointless here)

Well, a `String` will never equal a `String[]`, so there's the problem.

---

You will need to either

1) get an individual string from that array to compare,

2) Get an `R.string` resource, not an `R.array`

3) Maybe use some implementation of a `boolean contains(String[] strings, String findMe)` method. However, I don't know if that applies to the logic you have shown

4) Use some other conditional that makes more sense... like maybe you have `book.getSubject()`?

---

Option 1, for example...

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String s0 = title_subjects[0]; // Get just the first string

        Class clz = null;

        if ("Soft Computing".equals(s0)) {
            clz =  pdfviewactivity.class;
        } else if ("Web Engineering".equals(s0)) {
            clz = pdfweben.class;
        else if ("Network Management".equals(s0)) {
            clz = pdfnetwork.class;
        } else if ("Wireless Network".equals(s0)) {
            clz = pdfwireless.class;
        }

        if (clz != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityBookDetails.this, clz);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Using a `Map<String, Class>` would look cleaner than a long if-else statement